# How to resolve an error which i am getting when installing vscode for testing my extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I made a vscode extension from the github template now to test i have to run this command according to the guide

```
node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/test
```

Which install vscode to test my ext. But after it installs i get the output as

```
Downloading VS Code 1.54.3 into .vscode-test/vscode-1.54.3.
Downloading VS Code from: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.54.3/win32-archive/stable
Downloaded VS Code 1.54.3
Test error: Error: spawn E:\NewProj\glitter-ext\.vscode-test\vscode-1.54.3\Code.exe ENOENT
Exit code:   -4058
Done

Failed
```

In this i am not sure what shall i do?
My ext code is

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "hello-world-vscode-extension" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.sayHello', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I somehow managed installing the vscode to the `./vscode-test` folder. Now i wrote a test file some sort like this

```js
const { runTests } = require('vscode-test');
const path = require('path');

async function test() {
    try{
        await runTests({
            extensionPath: path.join(__dirname, "../dist/"),
            testRunnerPath: path.join(__dirname, "../.vscode-test/"),
            extensionDevelopmentPath: path.join(__dirname, "../dist/")
        })
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
}

test();
```

This flile is named as `test/index.js` now when i run this file everything is fine and vscode opens for testing and at the same speed it gets closed and displaying the console as failed:

```
Exit code:   1
Done

Failed
```

Comment: in which directory have you installed vsc: `./vscode-test` or `../.vscode-test/` watch the `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the current VSC by using an [additional Launch config](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#debugging-the-tests) and [write the `index.(ts/js)` file and your test files](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#the-test-runner-script).

Select this config from the Run/Debug bar and press F5.

Now there is no need to download VSC.

Comment: Well i need to update it as now i downloaded the vsc manually.to the `.vscode-test/` folder but now there is a new error forming when i test the code. Everything is fine but as visual code opens for testing it gets closed at the same time. No errors but the console says `Failed`